# What is the derivative of $y = e^{x-y}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that $y = e^{x-y}$, what is $\dfrac {dy}{dx}$?

I have tried taking log on both sides but that does not seem to lead anywhere, can anyone please send their solution with steps?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it satisfactorily answered your question

Answer (score 2):

Since $ye^y=e^x$, $(1+y)e^yy^\prime=e^x=ye^y$, so $y^\prime=\frac{y}{1+y}$. In terms of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), $y=W(e^x)\implies y^\prime=\frac{W(e^x)}{1+W(e^x)}$.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the natural logarithm both sides, we have:
$$\ln y= x-y$$
Now differentiating both sides:
$$\frac{y'}{y}=1-y' $$
 $$\Rightarrow y'\left(1+\frac1y\right)=1  $$
 $$ \Rightarrow y'\left(\frac{1+y}{y}\right)= 1$$
$$\Rightarrow y'= \frac{y}{y+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
y&=e^{x-y}\\
dy&=e^{x-y}\ dx-e^{x-y}\ dy\\
\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{e^{x-y}}{1+e^{x-y}}\\
&=\frac{y}{1+y}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this (sai-kartik & J.G. & Rezha Adrian Tanuharja are right):

Note that

$${\frac{d}{dx}e^u=\frac{du}{dx}e^u}$$

Given that $y=e^{x-y}$ , differentiating both sides and using the above rule (it is called the chain rule), we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(1-\frac{dy}{dx})e^{x-y}$$

Now expanding the right hand side, we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x-y}-\frac{dy}{dx}e^{x-y}$$

Now moving the second term on the RHS to the LHS, we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{dy}{dx}e^{x-y}=e^{x-y}$$

Now taking $\frac{dy}{dx}$ common on the RHS, we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(1+e^{x-y})=e^{x-y}$$

Now dividing both sides by $1+e^{x-y}$ , we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{e^{x-y}}{1+e^{x-y}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y = e^{x-y}\implies y e^y=e^x\implies x=y+\log(y)\implies x'=\frac 1y+1\implies y'=\frac 1{1+\frac 1y}=\frac y{y+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take log both sides
$$\ln y=x-y$$
$$x=y+\ln y$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=1+\frac{1}{y}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y+1}{y}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{y+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for editing.I am actually a newcomer over here and don't know how to write mathematical equations